# Video texture on blender cube displayed all over the cube, not separately on each faces while using it in unity

Tags: import, unity

i don't really know if it's an unity or blender related issue, but i believe this question belongs here (else i'am sure you'll let me know). Also it may seems newbish and that's quite true, i'am new to blender.

I've created a simple cube and done an UV map for it, then i'am importing it in unity so i can use it in my project.

My problem come when trying to apply an Unity Video texture to it: The display is shared across all the faces, scattering the video trought the cube, but with a default unity generated cube each face are displaying the video separately, like they all are independent (and that's what i would like to achieve with my blender cube, and later on, with a 3D custom object).

My question now is why is that so ? Where does this behavior come from ? Is it unity or blender related ? Am i missing something about UV mapping, advanced features i don't know about ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as i assume many noobs like me will possibly meet the joys of playing with UVs and so will they struggle with this aswell, here is the proper way to achieve this (as i said, i missed something about UVs):

In order to make sure each face is treated as an unique surface, go to blender, switch into edit mode and repeat this process for each and every single face of your cube/object:

- Select your face or the ones wich are part of it
- Ctrl + E -> make seam
- Press "U" -> Unwrap
- If you've done that right, the UV editor should show you only the shape of what you've selected.
- Redo for the next face until you've done that for each one of them.

Worked for me, spent hours wondering "How" Hopefully that will help peoples out.

Comment: What is described in question means you want to have each face as separate island in the UV map and they should occupy the same space on the UV space and hence shows the same texture piece for each island (often unwrap is done to achieve the contrary). To achieve this you can select all and press U > Reset so that all faces get unwrapped into stack of faces above each other.